# What are memory leaks in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I tried solving the extra credit of [exercise 16](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html). Even though it compiles properly, I get memory leaks.

Now I was of the notion that if don't use `malloc()` at all there is no way the program would leak memory, but here it does, because when I ran the command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./ex16-1
```

I got:

```
definitely lost: 21 bytes in 2 blocks
```

- Is it possible to have leaks even if I don't allocate any memory (given that there is nothing wrong with my source)?
- Also, if it is possible then how do I free that block of memory? Where does the memory point to?

The [full output of valgrind is available on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/MQ3hWueB)

And the [source code](http://pastebin.com/VNtPHz2d):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
  char *name;
  int age;
  int height;
  int weight;
};

struct Person Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight) {
  struct Person who;
  who.name = strdup(name);
  who.age = age;
  who.height = height;
  who.weight = weight;

  return who;
}

void Person_print(struct Person who) {
  printf("Name: %s\n", who.name);
  printf("\tAge: %d\n", who.age);
  printf("\tHeight: %d\n", who.height);
  printf("\tWeight: %d\n", who.weight);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  struct Person joe = Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);
  struct Person frank = Person_create("Frank Blank", 20, 72, 180);

  Person_print(joe);
  Person_print(frank);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your pastebin links both go to the same place, and it would be much more readable if you put the source code inline in a code block anyway

Comment: Line 71ff tell you exactly what goes wrong: `Person_create` calls `strdup`, which calls `malloc` internally, and you don't `free` the `char *` pointer.

Comment: I seriously didn't know strdup use malloc internally, I was really confused why valgrind even printed malloc! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ComputerDruid fixed the links, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: If you look at the `man` page for `strdup`, the description says: " The  strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3)."

Comment: @iobender After seeing wallyk's answer and Philips' comment I first saw man strdup, thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: Whenever you're suspecting a bug with your compiler, library vendor, hardware or government, the answer is always "no". It's in your code.

Comment: The link to _exercise 16_ is dead. That's why all relevant information should always be contained within the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program demonstrates a significant memory leak.  On many systems, it won't run very far.

```
#include <memory.h>

int add (int a, int b)
{
      char *hog = malloc (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 50);
      return a + b;
}
int main (void)
{
    int sum = add (add (6, 8), add (3, 7));
    return 0;
}
```

In the case of your program, it calls `strdup()` which calls `malloc`.  When you are done with the return value of strdup, it should be freed.

Comment: When I tried to open the link my firefox just freezes, does somebody know why? is there some evil javascript at the links?

Comment: The ones in the question.

Comment: @iharob:  Oh, then you should comment on the question, not on some random answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate memory dynamically it's your responsibility to *free* the allocated memory, i.e. give it back to the OS, so it can be reused, if you fail to free memory and it turns out that it is enough memory, your system could run out of memory, causing all running programs to fail and new programs would not be able to start.

If you don't use `malloc()` but some library you use or a standard library function does, then leaks will happen, one way would be

```
void function()
 {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/some/path/file.txt", "r");
    /* check that file is valid and use it */
 }
```

The function above leaks memory, because some resources allocated by `fopen()` are not released, you need to `fclose(file)` to prevent the leak.

Using [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) you may find cases where there is no apparent call to `malloc()` or any related function in your code, yet it reports allocated memory and perhaps released memory to you.

Comment: It usually does *not* go back to the O/S.  It goes back into the RTL memory recycler.  Normally runtime libraries do not deallocate any of the memory pool's memory (which would release it to the O/S).

Comment: Maybe you're right but that is a technical thing that seems irrelevant, the relevant thing is that `free()`ed memory can be reused.